# Merge two complex dictionaries in an ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I cannot find a way to merge two variables variables.
As they are used in several parts of my playbooks they have to stay in this structure.

What I want to do is set special ssh public keys when a host belongs to a specific group.

hosts:

```
...
[special-bla]
blahost1
blahost2
...
```

vars:

```
user_list:
  - user:     root
    uid:      0
    # ... other A settings ...
    keys:
      - {
          file: files/ssh/pubkeys/admin1.pub,
          options: 'from="10.28.89.0/24"',
        }
      - {
          file: files/ssh/pubkeys/admin2.pub,
          options: 'from="10.28.89.0/24"',
        }
      - {
          file: files/ssh/pubkeys/admin3.pub,
          options: 'from="10.28.10.32,10.28.89.0/24"',
        }
```

and

```
special_users:
  special_bla_users:
    - user:     root
      # ... other B settings ...
      keys:
        - {
            file: files/ssh/pubkeys/bla/bla_admin.pub,
            options: 'from="10.0.0.1"',
          }
```

In my ansible playbook I create a special_local_users list depending on if the host is in a specific group:

```
  - name: Create special_local_users list
    set_fact:
      special_local_user_list: |
        {%  for item in special_host_groups -%}
        {%    set section= item ~ '_users' %}
        {%    if special_users[section] is defined -%}
        {%      for user in special_users[section] -%}
        {{ user | to_json }},
        {%-     endfor %}
        {%-   endif %}
        {%- endfor %}
```

Now I want to merge the settings of the two lists. Which should result in

```
user_list:
  - user:     root
    uid:      0
    # ... other A settings ...
    # ... other B settings ...
    keys:
      - {
          file: files/ssh/pubkeys/admin1.pub,
          options: 'from="10.28.89.0/24"',
        }
      - {
          file: files/ssh/pubkeys/admin2.pub,
          options: 'from="10.28.89.0/24"',
        }
      - {
          file: files/ssh/pubkeys/admin3.pub,
          options: 'from="10.28.10.32,10.28.89.0/24"',
        }
      - {
          file: files/ssh/pubkeys/bla/bla_admin.pub,
          options: 'from="10.0.0.1"',
        }
```

My knowledge of jinja2 is very limited so I did not find a way.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!
   Lars

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for asking...
I found a solution by myself:

```
  - name: Merge user_list with special_local_user_list
    set_fact:
      user_list: |
        {%  set user_list_users=user_list | map(attribute='user') | list %}
        {%  set special_local_user_list_users=special_local_user_list | map(attribute='user') | list %}
        {%  set _users=user_list | map(attribute='user') | list %}
        {%  for item1 in special_local_user_list -%}
        {%    if item1['user'] in user_list_users %}
        {%      for item2 in user_list if item2['user'] == item1['user'] -%}
        {{
                item1.update(keys = item1['keys'] + item2['keys'])
        }}{{ item2 | combine(item1) }},
        {%-     endfor %}
        {%-   else %}
        {{ item1 }},
        {%-   endif %}
        {%- endfor %}
        {%  for item2 in user_list if item2['user'] not in special_local_user_list_users -%}
        {{ item2 }},
        {%- endfor %}
```

It does not look very cool, but it works.

It combines all values except the keys which are added.